# Cocos2d- x 3 installation issue in mac

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

[image]

When I am trying to install cocos2d-x 3,It gives me the error. Please see the screenshot.

My Bash File.

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you copied and pasted the error text instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: what's the error? i can't find out it.  did you excute the command "source /Users/jubinmehta/.bash_profile"?

Comment: Yes I executed it below result i got

Comment: -bash: export: `2/Projects/cocos2d-x-3.6': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `2/templates': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `2/Projects/cocos2d-x-3.6': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `2/tools/cocos2d-console/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: you extart the ndk or not

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is blank space on your path, clause with double quotation mark, like,

```
export COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT="/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Projects/cocos2d-x-3.6 2/templates"
```

Other path should be also clause with double quotation.

Or, to make it simple, you should not blank space on paths. Use other character like underscore("_") instead.